# Why can't I register my P2P application in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, p2p

I am trying to learn a few things about P2P. That is why I am trying to run this code sample below on my computer with Windows 8.1 OS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.PeerToPeer;
using System.Net.PeerToPeer.Collaboration;

namespace PeerChat
{
    public class PeerChatApplication
    {
        private static PeerApplication PeerChatPeerApplication;
        private static Guid PeerChatAppId = new Guid("2B6FFB9A-8BCD-4B2E-9958-090E2E6FB5D7");
        private static string PeerChatDescription = "A sample peer networking application.";

        static PeerChatApplication()
        {
            PeerChatPeerApplication = new PeerApplication(PeerChatAppId, 
                                                          PeerChatDescription, 
                                                          null,
                                                          System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath, 
                                                          null,
                                                          PeerScope.All);
        }

        public static void SignIn()
        {
            PeerCollaboration.SignIn(PeerScope.All);
        }

        public static void Register()
        {
            PeerApplicationCollection peerAppsColl = PeerCollaboration.GetLocalRegisteredApplications(PeerApplicationRegistrationType.AllUsers);

            IEnumerable<PeerApplication> findPeerApp = from peerApp in PeerCollaboration.GetLocalRegisteredApplications(PeerApplicationRegistrationType.AllUsers)
                                                       where peerApp.Id == PeerChatAppId
                                                       select peerApp;

            if (findPeerApp.Count<PeerApplication>() != 0) 
                PeerCollaboration.UnregisterApplication(PeerChatPeerApplication, PeerApplicationRegistrationType.AllUsers);

            PeerCollaboration.RegisterApplication(PeerChatPeerApplication, PeerApplicationRegistrationType.AllUsers);
        }

        public static void UnRegister()
        {
            PeerCollaboration.UnregisterApplication(PeerChatPeerApplication, PeerApplicationRegistrationType.AllUsers);
        }
    }
}
```

First off all you need to SignIn and Register afterwards. It works nice in Windows 7 (using administrator's login).

In Windows 8.1 I am getting this exception: "The windows Peer-to-Peer infrastructure is not licensed to operate on this platform".

Does it mean that Windows 8.1 OS does not support P2P?

Comment: I think the P2P components are not installed in Windows 8.1 by default.

Comment: @Amy - I looked through Add/Remove Windows features and it is not there. How do properly install it in Windows 8.1? (PNRP service is installed and running)

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry.  I've seen this same question before, but it was about a version of Windows Server.  I brought it up in case the same solution applied.

Comment: @Amy : probably you are talking about this link here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/p2p/2008/06/23/pnrp-and-windows-internet-computer-names-on-ws08/

Comment: @Amy - It looks like suggested solution is: don't forget to start PNRP service. But it is already running on my computer. So there is something else that is missing.